# using Python Menu package?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried installing the following python package:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Menu/1.4

on both OSX(El Capitan) and Linux Mint.

Using the examples given on the website to install and use this package, I am having an issue where the terminal displays the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    mainMenu = Menu(title,update=updateFunction)
NameError: name 'Menu' is not defined
```

However, if I move the python script(test.py) into the downloaded directory and place it along menu.py, it works by displaying the menu, but breaks after it runs:

```
1. firstOption
2. secondOption
3. thirdOption

>>> 1

ha
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    mainMenu.open()
  File "/Users/Brij/Downloads/Menu-1.4/menu/menu.py", line 46, in open
    self.update(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What is going on? Did i install this package incorrectly or am I reading the instructions wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I also have tried to install it with the download on the [Python menu](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Menu/1.4) page, and with [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip):

```
sudo pip install menu
```

none of the installations did work for me neither. Only it seemed to work when I did the `import menu` from the directory where `menu` was installed (`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/menu` in my case).

Then I found that `__init__.py` was empty:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path.

Putting the following line in the `__init__.py` file of the `menu` installation worked for me:

```
from menu import Menu
```

See more about the packages and this init file on the [Python documentation pages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Then however, trying the [example](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Menu) gave the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/menu/menu.py", line 46, in open self.update(self)
TypeError: updateFunction() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I had the update function defined without parameter `def updateFunction()`, since it is not defined in the documentation. In the `menu.py` code however it calls: `self.update(self)`, which is with itself (the Menu object) as parameter. So you should define the update function with the menu object as parameter:

```
def updateFunction(menuObj):
  print "Update..."
```

There is one more change you should make in `menu.py` since the default update function `doNothing` does not have a parameter:

```
def doNothing(object=None):
    pass
```

Comment: so most of those steps helped solve my issues. However, now when i run the script with my menu object. I select an option, and without outputting anything it prompts me for an input again. When i hit 'ctrl+c' i see all the output.

Comment: That is because after your function is called, the screen is cleared and the menu is shown directly after. To see the function's output, either put a `raw_input()` in the end of your function (`firstFunc`, ..), or change the `menu.py` code not to clear the screen.